# Lightening a border using CSS

Tags: css

I'm attempting to create a set of utility functions that will lighten the CSS border per a given percentage.  For backgrounds using linear gradients like this works and I've [implemented a set for this here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superfly-css-utilities-effects):

```
background: linear-gradient( 
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) ) !important;
```

However I'm not quite able to duplicate this for borders.  Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps have a look on this: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: I'm experimenting with that ATM ... just not quite getting it to click

Comment: You can update your current question with anything you have tried from the link I've provided previously. So I will try to suggest something what you have not yet tried.

Comment: This is my first attempt (See u-border-lighten, u-border-darken) towards bottom: https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-utilities-effects/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css